# SmtpClient.Send Exception

Tags: asp.net, email, https, smtpclient

My site sends confirmation emails from a purchase.  95% of the time, it works.  The other 5% after clicking the 'Confirm' button that runs the payment and should send the email, i get the following exception:

Details:

> Exception: Failure sending mail.
>
> Inner Exception: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server
>   Inner Exception
>   (2): A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond 72.167.234.197:25

The code to send the email is this:

```
Dim smtpClientPayPalSuccess As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
smtpClientPayPalSuccess.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
smtpClientPayPalSuccess.Send(mailMessagePayPalSuccess)
```

FYI: I have confirmed with the hosting that I don't need any credentials, or a different port number than 25.  This is also running over https.

Any idea why this would be happening only a small percentage of the time?

Thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the mail fails part of the time. As far as I know it could be scheduled maintenance of the firewalls or the mail server itself.

I would advise you to send the mail asynchronously, and not as part of the 'Confirm' button process. Just put the mail on a (persistent) store and keep trying to send it with some time in between.

Alternatively (and heartily recommended) is to send the mail from your app to a local mail server, and let that mail server forward the mail to `72.167.234.197:25`. That way you get the retries for free and the chance that sending mail to `localhost` fails is quite small (or it should be small).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and quite likely based on your exposition, that there are actual network errors that prevent your site from connecting/communicating with the SMTP server. This could be the result of too much traffic, or maybe slow network connections.  My recommendation would be to put a try/catch around the emailing code, and maybe retry sending the e-mail a few times before giving up.

When you mention that this is working 95% of the time it shows that the problem most likely lies outside of your control.

As a side note, you should maybe consider not giving up the actual IP address of your SMTP server (it is of no consequence to the question)

Comment: Oh, but I like the IP address. Maybe I can route my spam through it. Need some blue pills? Really cheap ... :)

Comment: I wasn't worried putting the IP in as it will reject any connection outside the host's network.